# selenium - how to select HTML elements which do NOT have a certain CSS property

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

the HTML looks similar to the following:
*note: to have better readable example code I abstracted the classes to the unique ones because they are a lot more (which are represented by "`...`").*

```
...
<div id=”container”>
  <div class=”classA1 classA2”>
    <div class=”classA1 classB1 classB2 classB3 ...”>
      ...
      <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: 17;”></div>
      <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: 30; opacity: 0.6; ”></div>
      <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: 20;”></div>
      ...
      <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: 24;”></div>
      <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: 19; opacity: 0.6; ”></div>
      <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: 27;”></div>
      <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: 21; opacity: 0.6; ”></div>
      <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: -15; opacity: 0.6; ”></div>
      <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: 22;”></div>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

I am using

```
elements = self.browser.find_elements_by_class_name('classC1')
```

to select the following elements:

```
  ...
  <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: 17;”></div>
  <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: 30; opacity: 0.6; ”></div>
  <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: 20;”></div>
  ...
  <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: 24;”></div>
  <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: 19; opacity: 0.6; ”></div>
  <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: 27;”></div>
  <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: 21; opacity: 0.6; ”></div>
  <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: -15; opacity: 0.6; ”></div>
  <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: 22;”></div>
  ...
```

**question:**

how can I achieve the following result which contains only elements which do **NOT(!)** have CSS property `opacity`:

```
  ...
  <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: 17;”></div>
  <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: 20;”></div>
  ...
  <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: 24;”></div>
  <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: 27;”></div>
  <div class=”classC1 classC2 classC3 ...” style="...; z-index: 22;”></div>
  ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `not` with `style` and `opacity` with `css_selector`

```
elements = self.browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.classC1:not([style*="opacity"])')
```

Comment: I was afraid it would be something "easy" :) ... your answer is bringing me closer and is working on `.classC1:not([style])`, but not on style property _opacity_.

Comment: :) "easy". thanks! I tried with _contains(@style,'opacity')_ but struggled badly...

Comment: @udo `css_selector` doesn't have `contains`, only `xpath`

Comment: yups. struggled with xpath... I didn't think this would be possible with `find_elements_by_css_selector()`

Comment: last note. command should be `find_elements_by_css_selector('classC1:not([style*="opacity"])')`, without the `.` before `classC1`. could not edit your answer.

Comment: @udo Are you sure? `.` represents `class` in `css_selector`. `classC1` without `.` is treated as  `tag name`.

Comment: yups. running `find_elements_by_css_selector('.classC1:not([style*="opacity"])'`throws error `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given css selector expression "..classC1:not([style*="opacity"])" is invalid: SyntaxError: '..classC1:not([style*="opacity"])' is not a valid selector`

apparently selenium adds the class "." automatically.
note: I'm running selenium 3.4.1

Comment: @udo Nice to know. I'm working with Selenium 2 and C#.